# Import Xml file into Database in Web app

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to read xml to database. I'm getting `systemnullreferenceException` error on line 1 of code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("File.xml"));
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVERCONNECTION" +
                       "connection timeout=30"].ConnectionString;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader);
string strxml = XDocument.Load(reader).ToString();
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlcmd.CommandText = "loadXML";
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmlstr", strxml);
sqlconn.Open();
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconn.Close();
```

Comment: Assuming this is a web application, is `File.xml` located in the root folder?

Comment: yes, it's located in visual studio root folders.

Comment: Nesting function calls is always a bad idea.  You need to test the result from this call _before_ you use it: 
  

      `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("File.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the `XmlDocument` from Xml file you can use the following `ASP.NET/C#` code snippet:

```
#region Read XML Document from file, ignore comments
/// <summary>
/// Read XML Document from file, ignore comments
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath">string</param>
/// <returns>XmlDocument</returns>
public static XmlDocument ReadXML(string filePath)
{
    XmlReaderSettings readerSettings;
    try
    {
        // check if document exists, otherwise exit
        if (!File.Exists(file)) { return null; }

        // reader settings to ignore comments
        readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        readerSettings.IgnoreComments = true;

        // load xml document
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file, readerSettings))
        {
            XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            _xmlDoc.Load(reader);
            return _xmlDoc;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
    finally { readerSettings = null; }
}
#endregion
```

I would also recommend to place your file `File.xml` in ASP.NET special `App_Data` Folder. The full path to the file can be composed using the following statement:

```
string _fileFullPath = String.Concat (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data/File.xml");
```

Alternatively, you can use `Server.MapPath()` method (the one shown above is much faster).

Hope this may help.